# Enable a Jbutton when row is selected

Tags: java, sql, jframe

How can i enable a disabled button when i click a row in a table?

Here's my current code:

```
public void disAbled2() {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tb_add.getModel();
        int row = tb_add.getSelectedRow();

        if(row>=0) {
            b_add.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.addlistSelectionListener()` to `Table` and use the event to enable the button

```
tb_add.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
  //enable button - put it in an EDT to be safe though
 }
});
```

This watches the `Table` for a `ListSelection` event, which calls `valueChanged` where you can make your changes

**EDT - Event Dispatch Thread**

You should use the EDT thread so make changes to GUI so that the only thread that makes changes to GUIs is that one to avoid interference, like so

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                b_add.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Unless the selection is changed outside the EDT some how, the valueChanged event should be triggered within the EDT, just saying ;)